# How to show that linear applications are closed and open

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, open-map, closed-map

Let $f: R^n\mapsto R^m$ a linear application.

Is $f$ closed? Why?

Is it open? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection $\pi_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is not closed.

Linear maps are open onto their image ([open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis))), between Euclidean spaces. Otherwise consider $f(x,y) = (x,0)$ on the plane.

Comment: The open mapping theorem requires surjectivity. For example $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ where $f(x) = (x, 0)$ maps $\mathbb R$ to the $x$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$ which is not open.

Comment: Yes the linear function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^2}$ with $f(x)=(x,0)$ is not open.

Comment: @dem0nakos Thx,I added an example. In topology open often means open wrt the image space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh , okay ! np :)

Comment: Why is $\pi_1$ not closed? I am struggling to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Ohh I just though of an example. Consider $S= \{xy \ge 1, x> 0, y >0 \}$, whose projection is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @Jsevillamol indeed that’s the standard example.